# Make huge model compatible for Unity

Tags: modeling, unity

I have a model of Villa, which is really huge as it has 3.6million vertices.

Right now the project does not even export as .fbx file as it takes too long(took over 6hours and still nothing)

I need to get this into Unity, but I suppose I have created too high quality model. Is there a quick workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Game engines more commonly use a modular pipeline for their assets, You'll almost never see one whole scene imported as one mesh.

What you should probably do is go in, select certain components of your mesh and separate it into it's own object. if you leave the origin alone then you can batch export each model into a folder, open that in Unity and drag all the objects into the scene at once and they'll be in the same exact position as they were in Blender.